# Theta divisor on the jacobian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Given a curve $X$ of genus $g$, and let $\Theta$ be a theta divisor on the associated jacobian $J$.

- What is the degree of $\Theta$? and does $H^i(J,\Theta)=0$ for $i>0$?
- is two theta divisor are differ by translation ?

thanks

Comment: Since $\Theta $ defines a principal polarization, the classical Poincaré formula gives $\Theta ^g=g!$; and,  yes, two theta divisors differ by a translation. Then  
$H^i(J,\Theta )=0$ for $i>0$ -- since $\Theta $ is ample, this is Kodaira vanishing theorem.

Comment: thanks abx, but does the second question implies that all theta divisors are irreducibles?

Comment: @AllyMath The theta divisor of a reducible ppav is not irreducible. For example, if $E_1,E_2$ are elliptic curves, then the theta divisor of $E_1\times E_2$ is $E_1\times \{0\}\cup \{0\}\times E_2$ (up to translation).

Comment: The question is for Jacobians. So yes, the theta divisors are irreducible by Riemann's theorem.